# Поочередное выполнение задач в Cron

Tags: cron, очередь

Есть 4 задачи в Cron, которые должны выполняться каждую минуту:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/user1781/public_html/test.php ?query=1

/usr/bin/php /home/user1781/public_html/test.php ?query=2

/usr/bin/php /home/user1781/public_html/test.php ?query=3

/usr/bin/php /home/user1781/public_html/test.php ?query=4
```

Но вместо того, чтобы выполняться каждую минуту, алгоритм выполнения таков:

```
Первая задача выполняется ровно через минуту

Вторая задача через 2 минуты

Третья задача через 3 минуты
```

А должны все 4 задачи выполниться через минуту, а не поочередно.

Comment: А что там написано, в crontab'е-то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*/1 * * * *`  на каждую задачу в crontab
или засунб все 4 команды в 1 скрипт и поставь его на выполнение на каждую минуту

Comment: @Baho, */1 что даст нам?

Comment: запуск команды каждую минуту, подробнее можно прочитать на вики